# Label position angle problem

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels

Why the "F" are not positionned all around the node ? And how to fine tune the position then ?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \x in {0,5,...,360} {
\coordinate[label=\x:$F$] (F) at (0,0) ;}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you want the F's to appear in a circle, then you should do something like: `\foreach \x in {0,5,...,360} {\draw (\x:1) node {F} ;}`. Is that what you were after?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would call that a bug. The documentation states, that the anchors are somehow determined on the angle given (and other aspects), but that the user can change them if needed. Alas, giving another anchor explicitely, doesn't change anything:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \x in {0,-22.5,-45,-67.5,90,120,150,10,20} {
\draw[red](0,0)--(\x:1);
\node[draw,pin={[pin distance=10pt,circle,draw,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]\x:$F$},circle] (F) at (0,0) {x};}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But you can circumvent it.

1. Create coordinates at the label positions. (Thus preventing miscalculation of any anchors.)
2. Place your label at these coordinates.

Code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach[count=\n] \x in {0,-22.5,-45,-67.5,90,120,150,10,20} {
\draw[red](0,0)--(\x:1);
\coordinate[label={[label distance=20pt,alias=l\n,coordinate]\x:}] (F) at (0,0);
\node[anchor=center] at (l\n){$F$};
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But the best answer (for what I want) is the shape=circle answer as I want to place once the F but precisly because there is plenty of things around (geometry picture). To bad that answer was deleted.

Answer (score 5):

The manual (PGF manual 3.00, section 17.10.2) does outline how the position and anchors of labels are computed and also states:

> If this is not desired, you will have to set the anchor
>   yourself

However I can't get that to work so...

The following simple hack might provide a solution. Note that the `label anchor computed` key must either be in the `label` (or `every label`) options or the scope surrounding the path (and definitely *not* in the path options).

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}

\makeatletter
\let\tikz@compute@direction@orig=\tikz@compute@direction
\newif\iftikz@label@anchor@computed
\def\tikz@compute@direction#1{%
  \iftikz@label@anchor@computed%
    \tikz@compute@direction@orig{#1}%
  \else%
    \let\tikz@do@auto@anchor=\relax
    \pgfmathsetcount{\c@pgf@counta}{#1+180}%
    \edef\tikz@anchor{\the\c@pgf@counta}%
  \fi%
}
\tikzset{%
  label anchor computed/.is if=tikz@label@anchor@computed,
  label anchor computed=true,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[label distance=2cm, every label/.style={shape=circle}]
\foreach \x in {0,10,...,350} {
\coordinate [label={[fill=red, fill opacity=.5]\x:}];
\coordinate [label={[label anchor computed=false, fill=blue, fill opacity=.5]\x:}];
\draw[black] (0,0)--++(\x:2cm);}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just for the record. You need to define the style for the node because by default, it is a square. With the defined shape=circle, the top right picture shows some precision problems, but this can be improved (gradually as shown below) by increasing the increment of angle so that miscalculation of anchor is prevented. Here the increment of angle is (top right) 5,10,15,20,25,30 (bottom right).

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{vertex/.style = {shape=circle,minimum size=2cm},
state/.style={draw=none,
  }}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]

\foreach \x in {0,5,...,360} {
\coordinate[vertex,label=\x:$F$] (F) at (0,0) ;}

\foreach \x in {0,5,...,360} {
\coordinate[state,label=\x:$F$] (F) at (0,0) ;}  % if `state` style is removed, one gets the same result for squared F.

\foreach \x in {0,10,...,360} {
\coordinate[vertex,label=\x:$F$] (F) at (4,0);}

\foreach \x in {0,15,...,360} {
\coordinate[vertex,label=\x:$F$] (F) at (8,0);}

\foreach \x in {0,20,...,360} {
\coordinate[vertex,label=\x:$F$] (F) at (0,-4);}

\foreach \x in {0,25,...,360} {
\coordinate[vertex,label=\x:$F$] (F) at (4,-4);}

\foreach \x in {0,30,...,360} {
\coordinate[vertex,label=\x:$F$] (F) at (8,-4);}


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: But even with a defined shape, your examples show that there is a precision problem drawing labels with explicit anchors.